# Add all the zip files to a new file

Tags: java, zip

Guys is there a way to add all the zip files to a new zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear... But you should have a look to the java.util.zip package...

EDIT : if you want to use a library, you can also take a look at the apache's commons compress library (at http://commons.apache.org/compress) that allow you to create an ArchiveOutputStream and add your files as ZipEntry (see the example in the javadoc : http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/ArchiveStreamFactory.html)

Comment: @vinze i should create a zip file which contains another zip file .

Answer (score 0):

yes. but the compressed file size don't change so much

This [article][1] explains it so well

Hope it helps you

[1]:  This article explains it so well: http://kb.winzip.com/kb/?View=entry&EntryID=104

Comment: @SDReyes is it similar to adding txt files to a zip file

Comment: Hi Suresh!
I know what you mean (both can be though as an big array of data). but their contents are quite different.
Hope it helps : )

Answer (score -1):

In a terminal (if your OS is Linux or Mac or you have Cygwin in Windows):

```
gzip *.zip > newzip.zip
```

Comment: The OP tagged his question with Java, so I doubt s/he's looking for a shell solution.

Comment: Um? `gzip` is for *.gz files. The `zip` and `unzip` utilities deal with *.zip files.